# IIS should not ask login prompt in windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-deployment, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-express

i have hosted a asp.net web applciation in windows server 2008 R2,IIS 7.0 which was developed in .net framework3.5. i have given the below authentications in IIS.
[image]

while i am accessing that website from the other network ,its asking for username and password of the server.

[image]

actually it should not ask for the login without enabling the ***Anonymous Authentication***  .

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063 Check why it prompts here, and that's completely irrelevant to server side.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to enable anonymous authentication - there's no other way to do this